# Tab fragment is getting the wrong bundle

Tags: java, android, fragment, bundle

I have a main activity called `RestaurantActivity` and 3 tabs on it. `MenuFragment` is the default tab and when user selects an item on the list, it starts `startActivityForResult()` and goes into `SelectedMealActivity`. After returning a result from there, it calls `onItemSelected()` in `RestaurantActivity` from `MenuFragment`. Finally, `onItemSelected()` method pass the data to second tab `OrderFragment` but it gets wrong data with `getArgument()` method.

**RestaurantActivity.java**

```
public class RestaurantActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

private String resName;
private static int tableNo;
private static String resId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant);
    resName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("resName");
    tableNo = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("tableNo");
    resId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("resId");
    TextView tableNoText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tableNoText);
    tableNoText.setText("Masa No: " + String.valueOf(tableNo));
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(resName);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                       .setText(R.string.menu_fragment)
                       .setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "menü", MenuFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
                   .setText(R.string.order_fragment)
                   .setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "sipariş", OrderFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
                   .setText(R.string.detail_fragment)
                   .setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "detay", DetailFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

}

public void onItemSelected(ArrayList<String> item){
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putStringArrayList("item", item);
    OrderFragment fragment = new OrderFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
}

public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private android.support.v4.app.Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
      */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("resId", resId);
            bundle.putInt("tableNo", tableNo);
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), bundle);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } 
        else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (mFragment != null) {
             // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
             ft.detach(mFragment);
         }          
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**MenuFragment.java**

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment{

private static final String MEAL_URL = "http://kacyakiyor.net/meals.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; 
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<String> resIdArray;
String resId, orderTabText, mealName;
JSONArray meals, resIdJarr;
JSONObject resIdJobj;
Meal clicked;
Set<String> clickedItems = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
ArrayList<String> clickedArr, orderedItem = new ArrayList<String>();
int clickedItemsCount = 0, itemCount = 0, mealPrice, tableNo;

public MenuFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);     
    resId = this.getArguments().getString("resId");
    tableNo = this.getArguments().getInt("tableNo");    
    try {
        resIdJobj = new JSONObject("{\"resId\":[{\"resId\":\""+ resId + "\"}]}");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        resIdJarr = resIdJobj.getJSONArray("resId");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        meals = new GetMeals().execute(resIdJarr).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<Menu> items = new ArrayList<Menu>();

    for(int i = 0; i < meals.length(); i++){            
        try {
            if(i > 0 && meals.getJSONObject(i-1).getString("type").equals(meals.getJSONObject(i).getString("type")) == false){
                items.add(new Header(meals.getJSONObject(i).getString("type")));
            }
            else if(i == 0){
                items.add(new Header(meals.getJSONObject(i).getString("type")));
            }
            items.add(new Meal(meals.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"), meals.getJSONObject(i).getInt("price")));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {    
    clicked = (Meal) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    mealName = clicked.getName(clicked);
    mealPrice = clicked.getPrice(clicked);
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectedMealActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("mealName", mealName);
    i.putExtra("mealPrice", mealPrice);
    startActivityForResult(i,1);            
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
            itemCount++;
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra("item");
            data.putExtra("item", result);
            ((RestaurantActivity)getActivity()).onItemSelected(result);
            TextView itemCountText = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.itemCountText);
            itemCountText.setText("Toplam ürün: " + itemCount);
        }
    }
}

class GetMeals extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, Void, JSONArray>{
    ArrayList<String> mealArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    protected JSONArray doInBackground(JSONArray... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray arr = null;
        try {

            resId = args[0].getJSONObject(0).getString("resId");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resId", resId.toString())); 
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(MEAL_URL, "POST", params);
        try {
            arr = json.getJSONArray("meals");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arr;     
    }
}   
}
```

**SelectedMealActivity.java**

```
public class SelectedMealActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {
private String mealName;
private int mealPrice, count = 1;
TextView mealNameText, priceText;
Spinner countSpinner;
EditText mealNote;
Button backToMenu, addToBasket;
ArrayList<String> item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_meal);
    mealName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mealName");
    mealPrice = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("mealPrice");
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Ürün Detayı");

    mealNameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mealNameText);
    countSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.countSpinner);
    priceText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.priceText);
    mealNote = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mealNoteText);
    backToMenu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backToMenuButton);
    addToBasket = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addToBasketButton);

    mealNameText.setText(mealName);
    priceText.setText(mealPrice*count + "TL");
    countSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    backToMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    addToBasket.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chosen_meal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
    count = Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());  
    priceText.setText(mealPrice*count + " TL");
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.backToMenuButton){
        finish();
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.addToBasketButton){
        item = new ArrayList<String>();         
        item.add(String.valueOf(count));
        item.add(mealName);
        item.add(String.valueOf(mealPrice));

        if(mealNote != null){
            item.add(mealNote.getText().toString());
        }       
        Toast.makeText(SelectedMealActivity.this, "Ürün sepete eklendi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("item", item);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }   
}
}
```

**OrderFragment.java**

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {

ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
int count;
double price;
String mealName, mealNote;  

public OrderFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if(arguments != null){
        ArrayList<String> item = arguments.getStringArrayList("item");
    }      
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the answer by using getters and setters instead of bundles.